# Object listed as null?

Tags: java, oop, null

Right now i'm creating a program in which you merge two arrays into one. It seems to pass every other test, except this one. For example, this is what my output is showing:

Banana
Apple
Cabbage
Carrot
Pear
Orange
Pea
Broccoli
Strawberry

*** s1 merged with s2 ***

PASSED:

EXPECTED -->

Banana, Apple, Cabbage, Carrot, Pear, Orange, Pea, Broccoli, Strawberry

ACTUAL   -->

Banana, Apple, Cabbage, Carrot, Pear, Orange, Pea, Broccoli, Strawberry

*New Test*

Banana
Apple
Pear
Cabbage
Carrot
Pea
Orange
Strawberry
null

*** s1 merged with s2 ***
FAILED:

EXPECTED -->

Banana, Apple, Pear, Cabbage, Carrot, Pea, Orange, Strawberry, Broccoli

ACTUAL   -->

Banana, Apple, Pear, Cabbage, Carrot, Pea, Orange, Strawberry

It finds Broccoli to be okay in the other tests, but in the output for the failed test it's listed as 'null' instead of broccoli. I've tried implementing a for loop near the bottom of my method that should resolve this by setting any null list items to a temporary copy of the list, but it looks like i'm going about it the wrong way.

```
public void merge(ArrayMerge<? extends R> collection, int offset) {

        int offsetCounter = 0;
        int thisCounter = 0;
        int collectionCounter = 0;

        R[] currentArray = arr;

        R[] templist = (R[]) new Object[this.size() + collection.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < templist.length; i++) {
            if (offsetCounter < offset) {
                try {
                    templist[i] = this.get(thisCounter++);
                    offsetCounter++;
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }

            } else if (offsetCounter >= offset) {
                try {
                    templist[i] = collection.get(collectionCounter++);
                    offsetCounter++;
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
            if (offsetCounter == offset * 2) {
                offsetCounter = 0;
            }
            System.out.println(templist[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < templist.length; i++) {
            if (templist[i] != null) {
            this.arr[i] = templist[i];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: never silently swallow exceptions `catch (Exception e) {

            }`

Comment: You should at least print e.stackTrace()